# iOS: Universal Linking add restrictions

Tags: ios, swift, ios-universal-links

There are 2 Apps in my case say `App A` and `App B`.

I want to use universal link to open `App B` from App A and do some authentication work. I will be sending some result from `App B` to `App A` after it completes authentication via `App A` universal link.

But the use case I am troubled about is I do not want any other app to open App B.

If my `HTTPS` universal linking `URL` gets exposed, I know that universal links can not work directly from browser but someone can create malicious app and can try to open the universal link from malicious app.

Is there any solution to that? Like restricting what apps can open `App B` via universal linking?

Please correct me if my understanding is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The developer of a malicious app cannot intercept ANY link they want, that's what your `apple-app-site-assotiation` is for. The connection between the app and the site works both way:

1. In your app you need to put a domain to your website.
2. Under `<your_domain>/.well-known/apple-app-site-assotiation` you've got to put `appID` and only the app with that specific `appID` will be eligible to handle URLs to of this domain.

Hope it answers your question.